# Activiti event listener on process variable update

Tags: activiti

To any developers familiar with Activiti, essentially what I am looking for and currently I cannot find in their user guide for the product, whether an event exists, much the like the other start task event listener or end task event listener, a listener which is fired on update to a process variable? So the task is very much in progress and I want to react to a change of state of one of the process variables..

Does anybody know if this is possible with the OOTB product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was just working on this today. I registered an EventListener and implemented onEvent().

```
runtimeService.addEventListener(new APIEventListener());
```

Then you can look at the event type and take appropriate action.

```
public class APIEventListener implements  ActivitiEventListener {

  final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Override
public void onEvent(ActivitiEvent event) {

  switch (event.getType()) {
    case VARIABLE_CREATED:
        variableEvent = (ActivitiVariableEvent)event;
        logger.debug("Event: "  + event.getType() + " "  
                    + variableEvent.getVariableName() + " (" + variableEvent.getVariableType().getTypeName() + ") = "  
                    + variableEvent.getVariableValue());
        break;

    case VARIABLE_DELETED:
        logger.debug("Event: "  + event.getType());
        break;
    case VARIABLE_UPDATED:
        logger.debug("Event: "  + event.getType());
        break;
   }

  } 
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am new to spring and activti.Can you please help me where  did you  put in                                 runtimeService.addEventListener(new APIEventListener());